# Why does typical commercial machine shemurah matza taste different than regular machine matza?

Tags: passover, matzah

Shemurah matza has several more stringent requirements over regular matza: it has to be guarded for longer, and the people making it have in mind that it's for the mitzvah of eating matza on the night of Pesach.

I understand why hand matza looks and tastes different than machine matza - it's made in a different way.  However, machine shemurah matza is, in my experience, typically darker and more well done (often slightly burned) than normal machine matza.  This doesn't seem to obviously follow from its definition.

Is it a consequence of the halachic requirements of shemurah matza?

Comment: I wonder if the production process is different for shemurah flour?

Comment: I always thought it was wholer wheat

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/17/opinion/sunday/why-is-this-matzo-different-from-all-other-matzos.html

Comment: I don't have enough personal experience in comparing the two. Just to be sure, for purposes of this question, you are talking about the same brand / manufacturer, right? I ask b/c from what I've seen, companies that make machine shmura don't make regular, but, again, I don't look that intently.

Comment: @DanF yes. I'm pretty sure Manishewitz makes both.  As does [Yehuda](http://www.yehudamatzos.com/passover-matzos-products).